# Hydro isolation for foundation cut out (edge, not face)?

Tags: basement, windows, foundation, sealing

I live in Europe with a house constructed out of perforated bricks. I have sub grade basement windows. Our home inspector pointed out that the foundation edges exposed by the window channel need hydro isolation. We already have a major problem with mice falling in there, then tunneling through the foam insulation/sheathing all around the house.

What is the correct way to seal these edges? Each layer is very uneven, so I see potential problems with asphalt based paints or membranes, but would appreciate all advice.

Hard to see in the picture, but there is a drain at the base of each window cavity for water egress.

[image: basement window]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, looks like a problem (and one I've never dealt with). But I will venture what I would do:

- clean thoroughly with scrub brush and TSP
- spray insect poison deeply into each crack and crevice and let everything dry out
- seal all cracks and crevices with low-expansion spray foam
- paint all with waterproofing mopping sealant (like Redguard)
- pack with latex-fortified/modified mortar and smooth trowel level, around each window, till it looks nice like a clean cement frame
- prime and paint